# how to combine 2 array into 1 array in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have 2 different array that I got value from different checkbox and now I want to combine those value into another array.

This is what I want to achieve.

```
output 1 : [5,6]
output 2 :[3,9]

result : [3,5,6,9]
```

assuming I have already declare the array and got the value for `dt_temp` and `ab_temp`
this is what I have tried

```
var a = dt_temp;
var b = ab_temp;

 result_temp.push.apply(a,b);
 console.log(result_temp);
```

but the current code I tried I only got this output. I got empty array []

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `merge` to combine them

```
$.merge(a, b);
```